# join multiple columns same table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns

I am trying to count the number of products used by our techs

the table is setup like

count1, size1, count2, size 2

```
$sql="select SUM(count1) AS count1, size1, SUM(count2) AS count2, size2 FROM PARTS WHERE crew='$crew' GROUP BY size1 ORDER BY size1 DESC";
```

that works but displays as two separate columns and I have to manually add the two together. When I tried:

```
$sql="select SUM(count1) AS count1, size1, SUM(count2) AS count1, size2 AS size1 FROM PARTS WHERE crew='$crew' GROUP BY size1 ORDER BY size1 DESC";
```

I receive the error: Column 'size1' in group statement is ambiguous. How do I proceed?

Comment: you can't define an exists column name with AS , size1 is already exists

Comment: Perhaps the table is set up wrong

Comment: perhaps it is but it's what I'm working with

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$sql="select SUM(count1 + count2) AS count, size1 FROM PARTS WHERE crew='$crew' GROUP BY size1 ORDER BY size1 DESC";
```

Comment: that works without error except the counts appear to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both size columns are interchangeable, you could union all two queries of each part size and then apply a `sum` calculation:

```
SELECT   size, SUM(cnt)
FROM     (SELECT size1 AS size, count1 AS cnt FROM parts WHERE crew='$crew'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT size2 AS size, count2 AS cnt FROM parts WHERE crew='$crew') t
GROUP BY size
ORDER BY size DESC
```

Comment: I received the error:   Query error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: the sizes are in the format 2x4, 2x6, 4x6 etc ... example would be... line1: 2, 2x4, 4, 2x6; line2: 1, 1x4, 2, 2x4; line3: 6, 4x6, 2, 1x4